# Save JAR for Java Applet

Tags: java, applet

How can you save a Java applet (JAR/etc) so it can be accessed later?

Answer (score 1):

By the time you see the Java applet, it's *already* saved to your machine.  You just have to copy it out of the cache/temporary directory.

Answer (score 1):

Open the Java Control Panel, in the *General* section click the button *Temporary Internet Files*, there you can find (and change) the location where applets and associated files will be saved into.